# Как короче записать эти объявления границ?

Tags: css

```
border-left: 1px solid #669966;
border-right: 1px solid #669966;
border-bottom: 1px solid #669966;
```

Comment: вообще не разбираюсь в css, но мне кажется что никак. Здесь обьявлены левая, правая и нижняя границы. Можно сделать одной строчкой (без учета положения) но границы будут везде, а вам не нужна сверху. Никак, ИМХО

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Идея: задать полную границу и обнулить лишнюю.
Вот пример реализации:

```css
.test {
  border: 1px solid #669966;
  border-top: 0;
  /* Демо */
  width: 150px;
  height: 50px;
}
```

```html
<div class="test"></div>
```

Comment: такой вариант ответа уже есть

Comment: @Alex посмотрите на время. Мой дан раньше.

Comment: да, вы правы. этот тот случай когда решают секунды) Вам +

Answer (score 5):

```
border: 1px solid #669966;
border-top: none;
```

Comment: Однако интересная штука - css

Comment: я отмечу решением как самое короткое решение. но это костыли.

Comment: @Khipster это не костыли) и было бы правильнее принять **первый** [ответ](http://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/579581/191745) от VenZell

Comment: @Alex неочевидное использование правил это костыли.

Comment: @Khipster не могу с Вами согласиться, для меня костыль это использование хаков и т.п.

Comment: @Khipster, это очевидное использование правил. Нижеследующие правила при равном весе селекторов перезаписывают предыдущие. Поскольку перезаписывающее правило менее полное, чем первое, была уточнена только часть составного правила.

Comment: Костыли это всё что лишний раз заставляет напрягать мозг.

Answer (score 1):

Можно менять стиль и цвет в одном месте вместо трех.
`border-width: top right bottom left;`

```css
div {
  border-width: 0px 1px 1px 1px;
  border-style: solid;
  border-color: #669966;
}
```

```html
<div>div</div>
```

Comment: Способ рабочий, но короче ли он?